# Why won't this table disappear?

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8

I want this table to disappear, but for some reason it won't.  What is happening?

I am using IE8.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .test_table
            {
                display: none;
                background: #fff000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="test_table">
            <tr><td>test</td><td>teh4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>te3st</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>tes4t</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>tes5t</td><td>t3eh4</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given table the `ID = test_table` for ID use `'#test_table'` If you have given it a class then you will use `'.test_table'`

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
    <style>
        .test_table
        {
            display: none;
            background: #fff000;
        }
    </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <table class="test_table">
        <tr><td>test</td><td>teh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>te3st</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tes4t</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tes5t</td><td>t3eh4</td></tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
    <style>
        #test_table
        {
            display: none;
            background: #fff000;
        }
    </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <table id="test_table">
        <tr><td>test</td><td>teh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>te3st</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tes4t</td><td>t2eh4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tes5t</td><td>t3eh4</td></tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

either way will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is wrong. `.test_table` selects a table with `class="test_table"`, but your own has an `id` instead of a `class`.

Fix it by either using `class` instead of `id`, or changing your selector to `#test_table` (`#` is the `id` selector).

Answer (score 0):

test_table id defined as a class, bud in the table, it has no class, just id "test_table". This is cortect:

```
<table class="test_table">
```